# .NET MEF: part versioning

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, assemblies, mef, .net-assembly

I'm exploring MEF, introduced in .NET 4.0, and I haven't found on the official documentation or on any other websites a real way to manage versioning.

I found this question [MEF Dependencies and versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4962638/5048049) but the answers are not satisfactory: it seems to me that with strong naming the core and the plugin are too coupled.

My example:

- part A import an interface ICar (version 1.0)
- part B export an interface ICar

Everything works happily.
After the release I decide to modify ICar to have a version 1.1 with a more complex ICar interface. Clearly part B cannot be loaded anymore. 
How is the best practice here? Obviously the correct way is not to change the interface ICar. But is changing ICar the neatest way?
On a blog I found that you need to:

- create ICar2 instead of changing ICar
- create (manually) an adapter for ICar
- import both ICar2 and ICar and the latter needs to be adapted to ICar2 using the adapter.

It seems that System.Addin (MAF) manages this scenario with a built in solution.

Any ideas so far?

BTW, MEF seems a real good technology, but the official documentation is not enough (as usual for Microsoft...)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Interface segregation here to try to simplify this. In your example you have ICart, so for the new functionality you could create a new interface ICarExtra with the new properties/methods (if you want this could implement the original ICar interface)

So now your PartB can still satisfy any import of ICart but you can have a newer PartC with the additional functionality that can satisfy an import of ICartExtra.

Alternatively, for a far more complex solution, you could create your own version of CompositionContainer and override the ComposeParts method with some custom functionality to make a more informed decision.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am currently using Interface segregation to add functionalities that are conceptually different (ITyre, IWheel, etc.). I am not sure it's the best way to extend ICar instead, but probably it's better than create adaptors. The other way you suggest seems to me more abandon MEF and implement your part loader, that can be a good way to manage things.

Comment: Its not really abandoning MEF, its enhancing it :) I think i have an example somewhere that i will put on github later if you are interested in looking at this idea in more detail. I used a custom CompositionContainer to make decisions about what implementation to use. For example, you could use the value of some global variable to get the code to change to a more verbose logger without having to restart the application.